# How to find the value of the common ratio in geometric series without the method of substitution

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

It has been sometime since I got myself to solve mathematical equations. So I can't seem to find a way to come to a simplified equation for finding the common ratio knowing the final sum and the value of n in the formula :

$$\text{finalSum} = r(1 - r^n)/(1 - r)$$

For example: 3, 9, 27, 81, 243

$$363 = r(1 - r^5)/(1 - r)$$

Given above is a very simple example. But I'll be dealing these in decimals. Is there any way of getting a simplified equation to get the value of r? Or is the method of substitution the only way?

PS: This is for a program I'm writing

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: The formula is wrong. You should have $a_1 (1-r^n)$ instead in the numerator where $a_1$ is the first term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In general there won't be a closed-form solution, but you can use a root-finding algorithm (such as Newton's method) to find the value of $r$ as accurately as you want.

Comment: @TobyMak, the formula may seem wrong, but the first term is same as _r_ . Based on the example shown in the body of the thread. $$3(1 - 3^5)/(1 - 3)$$ is the correct equation right?

Comment: @GregMartin, Thanks for that. I'll check it out and see if it solves my problem

Comment: Is $r$ for your problem is always a positive integer? If yes, an easy solution can be used.

Comment: @SahilKumar, yes it is always a positive integer. Could you please point me towards the solution that you mention?

Comment: Please, see my answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504839/how-to-find-the-value-of-the-common-ratio-in-geometric-series-without-the-method/3505967#3505967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is binary search based solution for program.

As $r$ is always a positive integer. You can start with say $r=1$ and than calculate the sum using,
$$
S = \frac{r(1 - r^n)}{(1 - r)}
$$
Let the given sum is $A$. You can than check if $A \geq S$, if yes than double the $r$.

Say, currently $r = 2^k$ for which $A \geq S$ and at $r=2^{k+1}$, $A \leq S$.

Then you know answer lies between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$. You can apply binary search on these values to find $r$ for which $A=S$.

Sum at each iteration can be calculated in $O(log(n))$. So, final Time Complexity for this will be $O(log(r')*log(n))$ (where $r'$ is the answer).

Note: This will always give exact $r$.

Ref:

[Binary Search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/)

[Calculate power in log(n) time](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/)

Comment: I did try this binary search approach initially. Because of the time complexity involved and the trouble you have to go through to setup the whole thing, I changed how I designed the algorithm to get rid of the problem entirely. To give a gist, I just generate a suitable _r_ value and use it to find the value of _n_. And my apologies for the delayed response. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will need some numerical method and more than likely, Newton would be the simplest.

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(r)=\sum_{n=1}^p r^n - A$$

Assuming $r>1$, you immediately see that $$r^p < A \implies r < A^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ which could be a good starting point (for your case, $383^{\frac 15}=3.286$).

So, let $r_0=A^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and iterates according to
$$r_{k+1}=r_k-\frac{f(r_k)}{f'(r_k)}=r_k-\frac{(r_k-1) r_k \left(r_k^p-1\right)}{(p (r_k-1)-1) r_k^p+1}$$

For illustration with a "serious" case, let $p=25$ and $A=10^{10}$. This will give us the following iterates

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & r_k \\
 0 & 2.5118864 \\
 1 & 2.4707994 \\
 2 & 2.4605423 \\
 3 & 2.4600107 \\
 4 & 2.4600093
\end{array}
\right)$$

Make it apparently more difficult with $p=123$ and $A=10^{345}$ for the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & r_k \\
 0 & 638.08429 \\
 1 & 638.07615
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to post your answer. I did some experimentation using the newton method and tried to change my approach to the problem and finally ended up with an approach which seem to work well.